# How would I listen for a set of transactions?

Tags: iota-network

I am currently polling the tangle using iota.lib.js + public nodes listed on the IOTA website every 2 seconds. I'm using "findTransactionObjects" to achieve this.

This is just a workaround for subscribing to the changes made on the tangle. It is eating up a lot of data so I wonder if there's a way I can get notified through websockets or something else?

Answer (score 2):

1. Setup your own full-node
2. Using ZMQ to get real-time data
3. Or, wrapping ZMQ to websocket if you need.